# Controlling the expansion of nodes in collapsible layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is the first time I am using D3 and force layout and I am customizing the collapsible force layout according to the requirements.However when I  click the node initially its expansion to the child level node goes out of screen which scares me when I put more json data into it.Please help me how can I control this expansion, I couldn't find any help on the web regarding it.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to share more code and, even better, a small example of what you currently have and how it differs from how it **should** behave. Otherwise, it'll be difficult to help you.

Comment: link to the code https://jsfiddle.net/vjeux/kb3gN/

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong url shared.I will just attach the code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/70qy8ps6/..code attached

Comment: See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initial positions of the `children` when they are expanded:

```
  var numChildren = d.children.length;
  var dTheta = Math.PI * 2 / numChildren;
  var r = Math.min(width/10, height/10);

  // Initially, distribute children in a circle with radius `r`
  // around the parent.
  d.children.forEach(function (c, i) {
    c.x = d.x + r * Math.cos(dTheta * i);
    c.y = d.y + r * Math.sin(dTheta * i);
  });
```

Otherwise, the initial positions of the children is randomly chosen from `([0, width], [0, height])`.

Also, you can reduce the [`alpha`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#alpha) to make the appearance a bit smoother.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/70qy8ps6/2/

Comment: Now on the first click it is fine but on the further clicks it creates the same problem..:(